# How to make Listbox just show one value of more than 2 same values C#

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

If i have the table Book with column Author | Title ... but if there are more than 2 Title has the same Author how can I show just one value of Author in listbox. Sorry because i cannot show any code and thanks in advance

I have my Load function like this

```
public void LoadData()
    {

            var orderedAuthor = (from Book b in BookDB.Books
                                 orderby b.Author
                                   select b); Data.Clear();
            foreach (Book m in orderedAuthor)
                Data.Add(m);



    }
```

help me to fix this code just to show the unique value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq

for example :

```
    public bool exists(string author)
    {
        bool hasAuthor = this.Data.Any(c => c.Author == author);
        return hasAuthor;
    }
```

and then you just call it

```
 foreach (Book m in orderedAuthor)
 {
           if(this.exists(m.Author)!=true)
            Data.Add(m);
  }
```

Comment: if I want to make it as a general function for all columns in my table...i.e Author, Publisher, Genre,.... how can i edit my code?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the method Distinct :) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx

```
(from Book b in BookDB.Books
                             orderby b.Author
                               select b.Author).Distinct();
```

this example is without access to VS :)

Comment: i dont understand your naming :) is fullname the author?

if so i have added the code.

Comment: sr sr for my mistake. cause i just want to show a simple example... and the code is different....now its ok

Comment: hey after I add your code, what can I do next? how can I call it as ItemsSource??

Comment: Use .ToList() in the end and set datasource to This list.